# Align the Data Table inside the container

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Align Data table in Flutter

```dart
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
        width: 370.0,
        height: 250.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,left: 167),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 100),
          child: DataTable(
              horizontalMargin: 0,
              columnSpacing: 20,
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('ID',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),)
                ),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('NAME',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),)
                ),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('AGE',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),)
                ),
              ],
              rows: [
                DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(
                      Text(
                          '0001'
                      )
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                      Text(
                          'Zisan'
                      )
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                      Text(
                          '16'
                      )
                  ),
                ]),
              ])
          )]

      )

      )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKsCj.png)

I need to align the data table properly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you have to change your padding by a Center. If this doesn't work, use mainAxisAlignement or crossAxisAlignement in your listview. Or try to wrap your Container with a Center.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
    width: 370.0,
    height: 250.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,left: 167),
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
    children: [
      Center(
      child: DataTable(
          horizontalMargin: 0,
          columnSpacing: 20,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
                label: Text('ID',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.red
                  ),)
            ),
            DataColumn(
                label: Text('NAME',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.red
                  ),)
            ),
            DataColumn(
                label: Text('AGE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.red
                  ),)
            ),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                      '0001'
                  )
              ),
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                      'Zisan'
                  )
              ),
              DataCell(
                  Text(
                      '16'
                  )
              ),
            ]),
          ])
      )]
  )
```

)